# Suppress read action in kendo grid mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How I can suppres read action in kendo grid mvc which depends on field in model which send to this grid?

For example I send false value and I dont call read action

Comment: pretty sure there is a AutoBind setting in the datasource config.. set that equal to your Model property..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JamieD77 mentioned one of the ways to do this is to use the AutoBind option of the Grid (not the DataSource):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<OrderViewModel>()
   .Name("grid")
   .AutoBind(Model.ShouldLoad)
```

Using the above approach however have some drawbacks - for example if the "Sortable" option of the Grid is enabled and the user try to sort the empty Grid, it will result in "Read" request (the Grid will try to fetch data from the server). That why I would suggest ot instead conditionally hide the whole Grid or conditionally remove the "Read" option of the DataSource and bind the Grid to empty array using it's "BindTo" option.

Answer (score 0):

I also need to conditionally suppress the grid's read action, based on a value in the model (there was no reason in this case to make a call to the server). Thanks to the answer by @Vladimir lliev, where he mentioned NOT using AutoBind, but instead removing the "Read" action from the DataSource and binding to an empty array.

This pointed me in the right direction, but I didn't know how to do that with the razor syntax. I figured it out, so I'm sharing for anyone else who needs this.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SomeNamespace.Model>(
    // If you need to optionally bind to an empty datasource in certain scenarios,
    // use the grid's constructor. Also, conditionally enable the DataSource's "Read"
    // action. Note: it's not enough to just conditionally enable the "Read" action,
    // since the grid still makes a request for some reason, but when you use an empty
    // array AND disable the "Read" action, no call is made to the server.
    Model.ShouldGridRead ? null : new SomeNamespace.Model[] { }
)
.Name("MyGrid")
.Columns(cols =>
{
})
.DataSource(ds => ds
    .Ajax()
    .Batch(true)
    .Model(model =>
    {
    })
    .Read(a =>
    {
        if (Model.ShouldGridRead)
        {
            a.Action("Some_Action", "Some_Controller");
        }
    })
)
```